# Vectorization of 3 particular nested for loops

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, nested, vectorization

I have 3 for loop and I want to vectorized it .

I try a lot to do it but I cannot do it.

This is the simple version.

I can't explain the whole situation but:

A is 100*82.

B is 203*2000.

C is 1*10.

D is 100*5*2000.

```
for nset=1:100
      for nindy=1:5
          for nimp=1:2000
  if A(nset,2+(nindy-1).*3)==1
      if B(33.*6+nindy,nimp)<= C(1+(nindy-1).*2)+...
          ((C(2+(nindy-1).*2)-C(1+(nindy-1).*2))./11).*A(nset,1+(nindy-1).*3)

         D(nset,nindy,nimp)=1;
      end
  end

         end
      end
  end
```

I want to replace the 3 for loops with vectorization...

Thanks....

Comment: I don't think is possible.

Comment: Do you have any internal dependencies? So to say, would you be able to handle each element without knowledge of the others?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! These lines should do it:

```
nset=1:100;
nindy=1:5;
nimp=1:2000;
D(bsxfun(@and, (A(nset,2+(nindy-1).*3)==1),bsxfun(@le,shiftdim(B(33.*6+nindy,nimp),-1),bsxfun(@plus,C(1+(nindy-1).*2),bsxfun(@times,((C(2+(nindy-1).*2)-C(1+(nindy-1).*2))./11),A(nset,1+(nindy-1).*3))))))=1;
```

By my computer it changed the run time from about 1 second to a 20th of a second.

Comment: I've tried and time was reduced by 50% but results seemes  to be not equal.....any suggestion?

Comment: I forgot to define the intervals. Hopefully it should work now!